# Bind JQuery UI Confirmation in asp.net OnClient Event of a Button Control

Tags: asp.net, webforms, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to bind a **jquery confirmation modal box** in my asp.net **OnClientClick** event of a server side button control. if the confirmation box returns true then **OnClicK** event will be fired and if the confirmation box returns false then the **OnClick** event will not be fired means no post back will be occurred. Can anyone please give me a suggestion how to achieve this.

Comment: One solution I have in my mind and that is to use Jquery ajax in Ok or Cancel option in jquery confirmation box. But I want to know if there any way to make this behave as like javascitpt confirm method does.

Answer (score 0):

Seems simple

Call one java script function in following manner

OnClientClick = "return ConfirmModel();"

Then Javascript for that will be

```
function ConfirmModel()
   {
     //Here write the logic of returning true or false.  
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of my problem is:

```
$("#<%= btnCancel.ClientID %>").on("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                myDialog();
            });

            myDialog = function () {
                $("<div>Are you sure you want to redirect?</div>").dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    width: 500,
                    height: 200,
                    buttons: {
                        "Okey": function () {
                            //Unbind the event 
                            $("#<%= btnCancel.ClientID %>").unbind();
                            $(this).dialog("destroy");
                            //Call server method
                            $("[id*=<%= btnCancel.ClientID %>]").click();
                        },
                        "Nope": function () {
                            $(this).dialog("destroy");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('Message');"
```